# Group action on cosets

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I would like to solve the Problem 2.19 from **A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics** by *Szekeres*. The problem is part of the paragraph 2.6 Group action. The formulation is:

> Problem 2.19 If $H$ is any subgroup of a group $G$ define the action
>   of $G$ on the set of left cosets $G/H$ by $g$: $g'H\mapsto gg'H$.
>
> (a) Show that this is always a transitive action of $H$ on $G$.

In the formulation in (a) *this* refer to the action mentioned before:
$G\to \text{Transf}(G/H),g\mapsto(g'H\mapsto gg'H).$

But the action mentioned in (a) is:
$H\to \text{Transf}(G).$

That is the two actions are not the same.

What am I missing? How should I understand the problem?

Note that I am not asking about the proof that the action is transitive, I am interested in the problem formulation.

Comment: It looks like a mistake. The transitive action in question is an action of $G$ on the left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Do you mean that the only change to make the problem statement correct is:"(a) Show that this is always a transitive action of $G$ on $G/H$."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action is of $G$ on $G/H$, where $g(g'H) = (gg')H$. This a trasitive group action (one orbit) since for any $gH,g'H \in G/H$, let $h = g'g^{-1}$, then $h(gH) = g'H$. Equivalently, for any $gH \in G/H$, $g(H) = gH$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking for a problem statement that makes sense, not for the solution.

Comment: @LiPo Like Michael said, you should fix part (a) by saying action of $G$ on $G/H$. That's the problem statement that makes sense.